# Filter Map and Reduce

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, foreach

I have the following line of code:

```js
          $scope.listDeColaboradoresObject.forEach(item => {
            item.listNmAssunto = $scope.relatorioTotalMensagensRespondidasColab
              .filter(x => x.nmUsuario == item.nmUsuario)
              .map(x => x.nmAssunto);
            item.listNmAssunto = $scope.removeDuplicates(item.listNmAssunto);

            item.listDtResposta = $scope.relatorioTotalMensagensRespondidasColab
              .filter(x => x.nmUsuario == item.nmUsuario)
              .map(x => x.dtResposta);

          });
```

that runs through this array:

```js
0: {deTipoAtendimento: "012", nmAssunto: "Cartão extraviado", nmUsuario: "15", dtResposta: "2018", total: 1}
1: {deTipoAtendimento: "012", nmAssunto: "Assunto Novo 012", nmUsuario: "Admin", dtResposta: "2018", total: 2}
2: {deTipoAtendimento: "012", nmAssunto: "Assunto Novo 012", nmUsuario: "Administrador", dtResposta: "2018", total: 1}
3: {deTipoAtendimento: "012", nmAssunto: "Assunto Novo 012", nmUsuario: "Administrador IMB", dtResposta: "2018", total: 3}
4: {deTipoAtendimento: "012", nmAssunto: "Assunto Teste GREAt", nmUsuario: "Administrador IMB", dtResposta: "2018", total: 2}
5: {deTipoAtendimento: "012", nmAssunto: "Thais 23042018", nmUsuario: "Administrador IMB", dtResposta: "2018", total: 2}
6: {deTipoAtendimento: "012", nmAssunto: "teste Alterado2", nmUsuario: "Administrador IMB", dtResposta: "2018", total: 1}
```

and that returns me the following array:

```js
0: {nmUsuario: "15", listNmAssunto: Array(1), listDtResposta: Array(1), $$hashKey: "object:2975"}
1: {nmUsuario: "Admin", listNmAssunto: Array(1), listDtResposta: Array(1), $$hashKey: "object:2976"}
2: {nmUsuario: "Administrador", listNmAssunto: Array(1), listDtResposta: Array(1), $$hashKey: "object:2977"}
3: {nmUsuario: "Administrador IMB", listNmAssunto: Array(4), listDtResposta: Array(4), $$hashKey: "object:2978"}
```

My question is how do I at the time of the map insert both the nmSubject and the dtResponse within the same array

Comment: Can you add what you would like the final array to look like?

Comment: @MattWay until now they are like this: `listNmAssunto: ["Cartão extraviado"]` and `
listDtResposta: ["2018"]` but i need something like this: `listAssunto: [{a: "Cartão extraviado", b: "2018"}, {...},{...}]` thx for helping

Comment: I‘ve tried to answer for your requirements, but as I wrote on Phone, not verified. Maybe you have to adapt your removeDuplicates function for objects though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don’t map into one object?
Like this:

```
          $scope.listDeColaboradoresObject.forEach(item => {
        item.listAssunto = $scope.relatorioTotalMensagensRespondidasColab
          .filter(x => x.nmUsuario == item.nmUsuario)
          .map(x => {a:x.nmAssunto,b: x.dtResposta});
        item.listNmAssunto = $scope.removeDuplicates(item.listAssunto);

      });
```

Comment: simple and useful

Comment: If you need to use a filter and a map together (2 iterations), maybe you should you try reduce. You can check inside of your reduce function the condition and returns whatever you want.

Comment: @OscarLópez I‘ll research and extend my answer then.

Comment: @OscarLópez I think Matt Way has given the answer with reduce, but for me filter and map are better readable.

Comment: @Nikolaus I used to think the same but with I little extra effort to understand (a very little) you can avoid two iterations. You can also make a classic for loop with an inner if and check.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've will just update the existing array. I'm not sure how it creates the output you've posted. But, looking at your output, I'm assuming you want to group based on the `nmUsuario` and create an array of objects with 2 array properties. You can do the following using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [destructiring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
const input = [{deTipoAtendimento:"012",nmAssunto:"Cartão extraviado",nmUsuario:"15",dtResposta:"2018",total:1},{deTipoAtendimento:"012",nmAssunto:"Assunto Novo 012",nmUsuario:"Admin",dtResposta:"2018",total:2},{deTipoAtendimento:"012",nmAssunto:"Assunto Novo 012",nmUsuario:"Administrador",dtResposta:"2018",total:1},{deTipoAtendimento:"012",nmAssunto:"Assunto Novo 012",nmUsuario:"Administrador IMB",dtResposta:"2018",total:3},{deTipoAtendimento:"012",nmAssunto:"Assunto Teste GREAt",nmUsuario:"Administrador IMB",dtResposta:"2018",total:2},{deTipoAtendimento:"012",nmAssunto:"Thais 23042018",nmUsuario:"Administrador IMB",dtResposta:"2018",total:2},{deTipoAtendimento:"012",nmAssunto:"teste Alterado2",nmUsuario:"Administrador IMB",dtResposta:"2018",total:1}]

const merged = input.reduce((r,{ nmUsuario, nmAssunto, dtResposta }) => {
  r[nmUsuario] = r[nmUsuario] || {nmUsuario, listNmAssunto: [], listDtResposta:[]};
  r[nmUsuario].listNmAssunto.push(nmAssunto);
  r[nmUsuario].listDtResposta.push(dtResposta);
  return r;
},{})

const output = Object.values(merged);
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your results comment, it looks like you want to group your list by `nmUsuario`, but create a single array of objects that hold the relevant `nmAssunto` and `dtResposta`. You can achieve this with `reduce()`. Basically, you create an object with an empty array for each `nmAssunto`, and push a new object into the correct array each iteration. Then use `Object.values()` to convert to the final output array.

```js
const data = [
  {deTipoAtendimento:"012",nmAssunto:"Cartão extraviado",nmUsuario:"15",dtResposta:"2018",total:1},
  {deTipoAtendimento:"012",nmAssunto:"Assunto Novo 012",nmUsuario:"Admin",dtResposta:"2018",total:2},
  {deTipoAtendimento:"012",nmAssunto:"Assunto Novo 012",nmUsuario:"Administrador",dtResposta:"2018",total:1},{deTipoAtendimento:"012",nmAssunto:"Assunto Novo 012",nmUsuario:"Administrador IMB",dtResposta:"2018",total:3},
  {deTipoAtendimento:"012",nmAssunto:"Assunto Teste GREAt",nmUsuario:"Administrador IMB",dtResposta:"2018",total:2},
  {deTipoAtendimento:"012",nmAssunto:"Thais 23042018",nmUsuario:"Administrador IMB",dtResposta:"2018",total:2},
  {deTipoAtendimento:"012",nmAssunto:"teste Alterado2",nmUsuario:"Administrador IMB",dtResposta:"2018",total:1}
]

const groups = data.reduce((r, { nmUsuario, nmAssunto, dtResposta }) => {
  r[nmUsuario] = r[nmUsuario] || {
    nmUsuario,
    listAssunto: []
  }
  r[nmUsuario].listAssunto.push({
    a: nmAssunto,
    b: dtResposta
  })
  return r
}, {})
 
console.log(Object.values(groups))
```